# Почему получаю только негативные тесты в модуле unittest на Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

В модуле `product_funс` у меня имеется набор методов:

`get_x()` запрашивает целочисленное число x (в диапазоне (0; 100),

`get_y()` - запрашивает целочисленное число y в диапазоне (1; 100),

`product()` - перемножает x на y и считает разрядность произведения,

`print_rez()` - выводит результаты в консоль.

В другом модуле, `test_prod` я написал несколько тестов, которые запрашивают из `product_funс` значения и сравнивают их через методы assert с ожидаемым ответом.

Однако я получаю только отрицательные (непройденные) тесты. Хотя в функции test_product() с параметром разрядности, равным двойке (как у меня реализовано), должны получат ОК. Почему этого нет? Это **первое**.

**Второе**: почему-то y в ходе исполнения теста запрашивается единожды, хотя в коде `get_y()` вызывается дважды. Почему?

**Третье**: почему-то x и вовсе не вызывается, хотя такой вызов `get_x()` определен в функции `test_negative_values()`. Более того: там еще и ошибка для икса: StopIteration

Тестируемый код:

```
def product(a, b):
    sum = a * b
    rez = 0
    while sum != 0:
        rez += 1
        sum = sum // 10
    return rez


def get_x():
    print("Введите x:")
    while True:
        num = int(input())
        if 0 <= num <= 999:
            return num
        else:
            print("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз.")


def get_y():
    print("Введите y:")
    while True:
        num = int(input())
        if 1 <= num <= 100:
            return num
        else:
            print("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз.")


def print_rez(x, y):
    print("Результат вычисления равен", product(x, y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = get_x()
    y = get_y()
```

Тестирование:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from exemple.product_func import product, print_rez, get_y, get_x

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.x = 3
        self.y = 4

    def test_product(self):
        self.assertEqual(product(self.x, self.y), 2)

    def test_print_rez(self):
        self.assertIsNone(print_rez(self.x, self.y))

    def test_is_int(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(get_y(), int)

    def test_get_y_negative_input(self):
        with patch('builtins.input', side_effect='-1'):
            with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                get_y()

    def test_negative_values(self):
        with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['2147483648']):
            with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                get_x()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```